# Eclipse crashes when I start WindowBuilder GWT

Tags: eclipse, gwt

Eclipse Error when I open WindowBuilder in GWT file -> crash (Linux):

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f59e6ac65a0, pid=25322, tid=140026564249344
#
# JRE version: 7.0_09-b30
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (23.2-b09 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libwebkitgtk-1.0.so.0+0x14245a0]  void WTF::freeOwnedGPtr<_GdkEvent>(_GdkEvent*)+0x15df0
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions on how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-7/
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
```

Answer (score 0):

The Windowbuilder is not compatible with 64bit. This is a known issue.

Comment: in windows I work with x64 java + eclipse + gwt - it's work - in linux not

Comment: There is some package missing under Linux. I dont remember the name. You can install it by hand and make it work under Linux as well.

Comment: I am an old guy and I do it this way: I build myself a simple HTML-page that represents the design and then I reconstruct it by GWT. This way you really get to learn GWT and after a while you can leave out the first step. Or: you could use Windows. But thats not recommended ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I have setuped it on fedora 17- 64 bit with some tricks:

1. Run "sudo yum install webkitgtk" command from terminal.
2. go to "eclipse.ini" file and add "-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.UseWebKitGTK=true" at the end of this file.

See [this](http://saeedzarinfam.blogspot.com/2012/12/how-can-we-run-swt-browser-inside.html) link.